# How to scope model through two level association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have models `User`, `Tagging`, `Tag`

**User.rb**

```
has_one :tagging
```

**Tagging.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :tag
```

**Tag.rb**

```
has_many :taggings
```

I want to scope the User based on the Tag's name. How to do it?

Currently, I know how to do the scope under one level association, for example:

`scope :with_tag_id, -> (tag_id) {joins(:tagging).where(taggings: {tag_id: tag_id})}`

But how to do more levels?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   scope :by_tag_name, ->(tag_name) { joins(tagging: :tag).where("tags.name=?", tag_id, tag_name)

end
```