# How to use filterrific gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I have used `filterrific` gem to filter the model in rails.

Currently, I have three model, `Video`, `Tagging`, `Tag`

**Video.rb**

```
has_one :tagging
has_one :tag, through: :tagging

scope :by_tag, -> (tag_id) {joins(:tagging).where(taggings: {tag_id: tag_id})}
```

Because it's hard to use `tag.name` to do the filter(see [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715101/how-to-scope-model-through-two-level-association-in-rails/34722053#34722053)), so I use `tag_id` in join table `tagging` to do the filter.

**Tagging.rb**

```
belongs_to :video
belongs_to :tag
```

**Tag.rb**

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :videos, through: :taggings
```

Currently, the `scope` is working, but I don't know how to write **controller** and **view**

In controller: How to write `select_options` method?

In view: How to write `select` method? Currently, I write like this, but not working:

```
f.select(:by_tag, Tag.all, { include_blank: '- Any -' }, :class=>'form-control')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select options that go to the `select` tag helper need to look like an array of pairs `[ [ name, id ], [ name, id ] ... ]`.  Try something like this:

```
f.select(:by_tag, Tag.all.map {|tag| [tag.name, tag.id]}, { include_blank: '- Any -' }, :class=>'form-control')
```

Or to keep things even cleaner, you could use the rails `collection_select` helper with something like

```
f.collection_select(:by_tag, Tag.all, :id, :name, prompt: '- Any -', class: 'form-control')
```

The second one many need tweaking depending on what your controller is doing with the blank option.

There are good examples on [APIDock ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper#select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select).